# Printing a string created in a local function

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, buffer, local

I understand that the problem with the code below is that the char array, where the input is stored, is in a local function. When the pointer to that char array is passed to the main function, that char array should be deleted from the stack.

However when I try printing the string, it prints despite the compiler warnings. But if I try to put a timer in between the function call and the print statement the string is empty.
Why is this? Is the "garbage collection" slower than the print statement?

Output without the sleep:

> "String is [string]"

Output with the sleep:

> "String is "

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX 20

char* get_user_input();
int main (){
    char *choice;
    choice = get_user_input();
    //sleep(1);
    //Add sleep and it won't print
    printf("String: %s\n", choice);

}

char* get_user_input( ) {
    char inbuffer[MAX];
    char *pos;
    printf("Enter string>");
    fgets (inbuffer, MAX, stdin);
    pos = strchr( inbuffer, '\n' );
    if ( pos != NULL ){
        *pos = '\0';
    }
    return inbuffer;
}
```

Comment: Probably the same memory used for variables of sleep function. Try another function to see the affect of that function.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You should really read the question.

Comment: There is no garbage collection in C, at least not per default. It's more likely that the call to `sleep` overwrites your stack and corrupts the string. (That doesn't explain why `printf` leaves it intact, though.)

Comment: Why the sleep does change it? Well, i don´t know, because using the returned variable results just in undefined behaviour. Anything can happen. If you know it is wrong, then don´t do it...problem solved.

Comment: @MOehm So the stack has to be overwritten to be cleared in C?

Comment: Yes, RAM/HDD/... memory in general has to be overwritten to change. There is no possibiliy to "just make it empty"

Comment: @Diti yes I should, delete comment. (usually I like to read long answers and short question :P)

Comment: @deviantfan What do you mean by undefined behaviour?

Comment: No. Subsequent calls use the same stack space. The space is neither cleared upon leaving a function nor on entering it. That is why automatic variables often have garbage values if you don't initialise them properly. I wouldn't delve too deep into this, really. You have already found out that you can't return the local variable. Everything else is speculation and not worth investigating.

Comment: @dani-h: Anything can happen, and it is (pretty much) unpredictable. Maybe it works, maybe it crashes, maybe it is doing something what will cause problems in the future (but not right now). Or maybe it orders pizza...

Comment: Most modern compilers will issue a warning if you return an address of a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will primarily be due to the stack being re-written, consider:

```
char* get_user_input( ) {
    char inbuffer[MAX];
    char *pos;
    ...
}

void anotherfunc( ) {
    char a[MAX];
    char *b;
}

int main (){
    char *choice;
    choice = get_user_input();
    anotherfunc();
    printf("String: %s\n", choice);
}
```

The call to `anotherfunc` will use the same stack memory as get_user_input(), in this case nothing is actually written to a[] or *b, so your *choice may persist - just. If a function has any local variables which are written to, the invalid `choice` pointer will point to whatever is written there.